# Error While converting Dicom tags into excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pydicom

I am trying to convert and list DICOM tags from .dcm files into Excel (using pydicom), but it is showing an error while converting

Some of the tags are showing 'None' in the Excel file although they contain/show data ('FileMetaInformationGroupLength', 'FileMetaInformationVersion', 'MediaStorageSOPClassUID', 'MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID', 'TransferSyntaxUID') in DICOM format. How can I resolve this?

How can I resolve this?

Here is my code :

```
    import xlsxwriter 
    import sys 
    import pydicom 
    import os.path
    from pydicom.valuerep import PersonName
    keywords = ('FileMetaInformationGroupLength', 'FileMetaInformationVersion', 'MediaStorageSOPClassUID', 'MediaStorageSOPInstanceUID', 'TransferSyntaxUID', 'ImplementationClassUID', 'ImplementationVersionName', 'SpecificCharacterSet', 'ImageType', 'SOPClassUID', 'SOPInstanceUID', 'StudyDate', 'SeriesDate', 'AcquisitionDate', 'ContentDate', 'StudyTime', 'SeriesTime', 'AcquisitionTime', 'ContentTime', 'AccessionNumber', 'Modality', 'PresentationIntentType', 'Manufacturer', 'InstitutionName', 'InstitutionAddress', 'ReferringPhysicianName', 'StationName', 'StudyDescription', 'SeriesDescription', 'InstitutionalDepartmentName', 'ManufacturerModelName', 'ReferencedPerformedProcedureStepSequence1item(s)-', 'ReferencedSOPClassUID', 'ReferencedSOPInstanceUID', 'DerivationDescription', 'SourceImageSequence', 'ReferencedSOPClassUID', 'ReferencedSOPInstanceUID', 'SpatialLocationsPreserved', 'AnatomicRegionSequence', 'CodeValue', 'CodingSchemeDesignator', 'CodeMeaning', 'PatientName', 'PatientID', 'PatientBirthDate', 'PatientSex', 'PatientAge', 'Contrast/BolusAgent', 'BodyPartExamined', 'KVP', 'DeviceSerialNumber', 'SoftwareVersions', 'ProtocolName', 'DistanceSourcetoDetector', 'DistanceSourcetoPatient', 'EstimatedRadiographicMagnificatio', 'TableAngle', 'TableType', 'FieldofViewShape', 'FieldofViewDimension', 'ExposureTime', 'X-RayTubeCurrent', 'Exposure', 'ExposureinuAs', 'RectificationType', 'ImagerPixelSpacing', 'Grid', 'FocalSpot', 'AnodeTargetMaterial', 'BodyPartThickness', 'CompressionForce', 'AcquisitionDeviceProcessingDescription', 'AcquisitionDeviceProcessingCode', 'RelativeX-RayExposure', 'TomoLayerHeight', 'PositionerType', 'PositionerPrimaryAngle', 'PositionerSecondaryAngle', 'DetectorPrimaryAngle', 'DetectorSecondaryAngle', 'ShutterShape', 'ShutterLeftVerticalEdge', 'ShutterRightVerticalEdge', 'ShutterUpperHorizontalEdge', 'ShutterLowerHorizontalEdge', 'ViewPosition', 'DetectorConditionsNominalFlag', 'DetectorTemperature', 'DetectorType', 'DetectorConfiguration', 'DetectorDescription', 'DetectorMode', 'DetectorID', 'DateofLastDetectorCalibration', 'TimeofLastDetectorCalibration', 'ExposuresonDetectorSinceLastCa', 'ExposuresonDetectorSinceManufac', 'DetectorTimeSinceLastExposure', 'DetectorActiveTime', 'DetectorActivationOffsetFromExp', 'DetectorBinning', 'DetectorElementPhysicalSize', 'DetectorElementSpacing', 'DetectorActiveShape', 'DetectorActiveDimension', 'DetectorActiveOrigin', 'FieldofViewOrigin', 'FieldofViewRotation', 'FieldofViewHorizontalFlip', 'FilterMaterial', 'FilterThicknessMinimum', 'FilterThicknessMaximum', 'ExposureControlMode', 'ExposureControlModeDescription', 'ExposureStatus', 'ExposureTimeinuS', 'X-RayTubeCurrentinuA', 'PrivateCreator', 'Privatetagdata', 'StudyInstanceUID', 'SeriesInstanceUID', 'StudyID', 'SeriesNumber', 'AcquisitionNumber', 'InstanceNumber', 'PatientOrientation', 'FrameofReferenceUID', 'ImageLaterality', 'ImagesinAcquisition', 'PositionReferenceIndicator', 'ImageComments', 'SamplesperPixel', 'PhotometricInterpretation', 'Rows', 'Columns', 'BitsAllocated', 'BitsStored', 'HighBit', 'PixelRepresentation', 'PixelPaddingValue', 'QualityControlImage', 'BurnedInAnnotation', 'PixelIntensityRelationship', 'PixelIntensityRelationshipSign', 'WindowCenter', 'WindowWidth', 'RescaleIntercept', 'RescaleSlope', 'RescaleType', 'WindowCenter&WidthExplanation', 'BreastImplantPresent', 'PartialView', 'LossyImageCompression', 'PrivateCreator', 'CSAImageHeaderType', 'CSAImageHeaderVersion', 'CSAImageHeaderInfo', 'CSASeriesHeaderType', 'CSASeriesHeaderVersion', 'CSASeriesHeaderInfo', 'RequestedProcedureDescription', 'PerformedProcedureStepStartDate', 'PerformedProcedureStepStartTime', 'PerformedProcedureStepID', 'PerformedProcedureStepDescriptio', 'EntranceDose', 'DistanceSourcetoEntrance', 'OrganDose', 'OrganExposed', 'AcquisitionContextSequence', 'ReasonForPerformedProcedureCodeSequence', 'CodeValue', 'CodingSchemeDesignator', 'CodeMeaning', 'EntranceDoseinmGy', 'PrivateCreator', 'ReasonfortheRequestedProcedure', 'CalibrationImage', 'PrivateCreator', 'Privatetagdata', 'Privatetagdata', 'Privatetagdata', 'ViewCodeSequence', 'CodeValue', 'CodingSchemeDesignator', 'CodeMeaning', 'ViewModifierCodeSequence', 'PrivateCreator', 'ProjectionViewDisplayString', 'PresentationLUTShape')

    # ...
                
    dcm_files = [r"C:\Users\akhil\Downloads\CD no.2\CD no.2\MedVision\image\371203\1.3.12.2.1107.5.12.7.4405.30000013122104435475000000004\1.3.12.2.1107.5.12.7.4405.30000013122104435490600001421\img_1_1_1_1.dcm"]   

    for dcm_file in dcm_files:
        ds = pydicom.filereader.dcmread(dcm_file)
        workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(os.path.basename(dcm_file) + '.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

        row = 0
        col = 0

        for keyword in keywords:
            value = ds.get(keyword, "None")
            if isinstance(value, list):
                value = ", ".join([str(x) for x in value])
            elif isinstance(value, PersonName):
                value = str(value)
            worksheet.write(row, col, keyword)
            worksheet.write(row + 1, col, value)
            col += 1

    workbook.close()
```

Here is the data from DICOM tag:

(0002, 0000) File Meta Information Group Length  UL: 188

(0002, 0001) File Meta Information Version       OB: b'\x00\x01'

(0002, 0002) Media Storage SOP Class UID         UI: Digital Mammography X-Ray Image Storage - For Presentation

(0002, 0003) Media Storage SOP Instance UID      UI: 1.3.12.2.1107.5.12.7.4405.30000013122104435490600001313

(0002, 0010) Transfer Syntax UID                 UI: Explicit VR Little Endian

(0002, 0012) Implementation Class UID            UI: 1.2.40.0.13.1.1

(0002, 0013) Implementation Version Name         SH: 'dcm4che-1.4.7'

Answer (score 1):

The File Meta elements are in the [FileDataset.file_meta](https://pydicom.github.io/pydicom/stable/reference/generated/pydicom.dataset.FileDataset.html#pydicom.dataset.FileDataset.file_meta) attribute as they're not strictly part of the SOP Instance and are instead required when writing to the [DICOM File Format](http://dicom.nema.org/medical/dicom/current/output/chtml/part10/chapter_7.html).

```py
>>> ds.file_meta.TransferSyntaxUID
'1.2.840.10008.1.2.1'
>>> ds.file_meta.get("TransferSyntaxUID")
'1.2.840.10008.1.2.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use dicom-csv python package. It was designed specifically to collect all available metadata from dicom files stored in some folder tree (and it uses pydicom to read and manipulate dicom files). https://pypi.org/project/dicom-csv/

Once installed (`pip install dicom-csv`) you could collect all public dicom tags from all dicom images from some folder by

```
from dicom_csv import join_tree

df = join_tree('path/to/folder', relative=False, verbose=1)
```

resulting pandas.DataFrame will contain different DICOM tags as separate columns (except for pixel_array data), and several additional columns, like FileName, HasPixelArray.

[image]